# How do I get JavaScript code in a bookmarklet to execute after I open a new webpage in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out how I can get my bookmarklet to work the way I want it to. Here's my issue. I have a JS bookmarklet that scrapes a secure web page and uses those DOM elements to run my code.

My issue is, when I click on my bookmarklet, it opens the new page in a new tab and immediately starts running the code I intend to run for the newly opened page. For example, a prompt window that I'm using to store user input runs immediately on the current page I'm on when I click the bookmarklet. My intended behavior is to first open the new page in a new tab, load the page, then run the prompt and the rest of the code using the DOM elements of that new page. I'm using a secure webpage so I'll use google homepage for an example.

Here's an example:

```
javascript: (function() {

function OpenInNewTab(url){
  var win = window.open(url);
  win.focus();
}
OpenInNewTab("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl");

var prmt = prompt("Enter a date:");
window.onload = prmt;

})();
```

Ultimately, I'd like the code to do 3 things.

1. Open the new window in a new tab when clicking on it from any page
2. Be in that new tab and load the page
3. Then run my code on that newly opened page

I hope I have explained myself well! As always, any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you cannot do this because you cannot inject your JS in the new tab without user interaction.

Comment: simply click the bookmarklet again.

Comment: @dandavis I'm unable to click the bookmarklet again until I've interacted with the prompt window. I think what fernandosavio was saying might have something to do with it.

Comment: you need to upgrade your bookmarklet to greasemonkey or tampermonkey to cross domain lines like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the correct window. It would be easiest to have the same `id` on each separate page you want to click on, then include the following script through the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag.

```
function openInNewTab(clickElement, url){
  clickElement.onclick = function(){
    var win = open(url);
    win.focus();
    var prm = win.prompt('Enter a Date: ', 'March 11, 2015');
    if(prm){
      console.log('The Date You Entered was: '+prm);
    }
    return win;
  }
}
var pre = onload; // previous onload
onload = function(){ // window is implicit
  if(pre)pre();
  var newWin = openInNewTab(document.getElementById('click_input_id'), 'https://www.google.com')
}
```